# Windows Workflow Foundation: wait for a portion of a workflow to complete?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I am familiar with bookmarks, async and sync workflows as a whole, but what I need to do is to resume a bookmark and then wait (synchronously) for another step (state) in my workflow to be reached before retrieving the result, less I get the state from a previous run. Is there any way to achieve this?